# Get object-space positions of joined instances' vertices?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I have several curves joined and transformed to a mesh after scale and position changes. Now I want to animate them making a smooth growth, e.g simply by Z coordinate, but when I try to do this, turns out curves instances keep their original individual locations and transformations `:(` How can I retrieve vertices positions in object space to animate branches growth?

Here is my bush consisting of several curves:

[image: Branches]

And this is how I try to make portion of it:

[image: separate z after geometry join]

As you can see, different curves get cut relatively to their initial origin and scale, but I want to trim they by common coordinates space.

Here is a simplified version of my file:

[image]

Comment: Please provide more context. I think what you might want to do to use a *set position* and not delete geometry, and also to do this before *curve to mesh*.

Comment: Maybe a Trim .. hard to say.. please share a relevant chunk of your file on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @shmuel I added more info to make it clearer. I want to trim or cut by an animated portion factor so that smaller branches start growing together with the main branch at heir junction. This is why I tried to do this after converting to a mesh, to calculate positions in a common space, but got no success.

Comment: @RobinBetts actually I think trim is opposite of what I want because it works with each curve independently, and I aim to cut them together. Strange that it doesn't work after merging into a single mesh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read the docs tried out all the existing nodes and dozens of their configurations and found a solution: **Realize Instances** node which truly join instances into pure geometry without different scales and origins.

However, this leads to highly increased number of vertices, edges, etc. So, I'd be glad to see a more performant solution!

[image: Correct branches grow]